# Adding -std=gnu++11 compiler flag to QMake

Tags: qt, g++, mingw, qt5, qmake

I am compiling qt5.7 on windows with mingw32 and g++.4.9.3. 
While executing the configure.bat, I get this error :

```
C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0\configure.bat -prefix C:\Qt-5.7 -skip qttools -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine -skip qtcharts -skip qtdatavis3d -platform win32-g++
```

> C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0\qtbase/qmake/library/qmakebuiltins.cpp: In member function 'QByteArray QMakeEvaluator::getCommandOutput(const QString&) const':
>   C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0\qtbase/qmake/library/qmakebuiltins.cpp:419:94: error: '_popen' was not declared in this scope
>                                   + QLatin1String(" && ") + args).toLocal8Bit().constData(), "r")) {

The command that leads to this error is :

> g++ -c -o qmakebuiltins.o -std=c++11 -DUNICODE -ffunction-sections -g  -IC:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0\qtbase/qmake + lot of stuff

Also, the following code :

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
     FILE * f = popen( argv[ 1 ], "r" );
     return 0;
}
```

doesn't compile with

> g++ -std=c++11 mytest.cpp -o mytest

but with :

```
>g++ -std=gnu++11 mytest.cpp -o mytest
```

So the question is how can I modify the option c++11 to gnu++11 which is passed to g++ by the configure file ?
Thank you

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980499/where-in-qt-creator-do-i-pass-arguments-to-a-compiler

Answer (score 2):

Adding compiler options is quite easy in Qt. Just add the following lines some where in your qmake file.

```
# C++ Compiler flags: Gnu C++ Extensions
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
```

Similarly if you want to pass `C` compiler options, use this

```
# C Compiler flags for qmake 
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -std=gnu99
```

The reason `_popen` does not work with `c++11` is that its implemented as a GNU C++ Extension and is not in standard C++. Similarly, VisualStudio too defines `_popen` separately from the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Qt's Wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_use_C%2B%2B11_in_your_Qt_Projects), with the current version of qmake you are using, you can also use `CONFIG += c++11`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by downloading another version of mingw on the download repository of qt : [here](https://download.qt.io/online/qt5/windows/x86/online_repository/)