# MinGW / CxxTest bizarre errors

Tags: c++, mingw, cxxtest

I hope you can help me. I have written a small project using CxxTest on my main dev machine. Everything works great on this machine, no problems. However, I tried setting up this project on my brand new laptop and just can't get it to work! I suspect something is messed up with my MinGW installation rather than CxxTest, but it's really hard to know - and the errors originate from CxxTest files. This is the folder structure of the project:

```
lib/
    cxxtest-4.3/
src/
    TestUtils.h
    test.cpp
test/
    MyTestSuite.h
    libstdc++-6.dll
```

On the command line I run:

```
cd test
..\lib\cxxtest-4.3\bin\cxxtestgen --error-printer -o runner.cpp MyTestSuite.h
```

This generates runner.cpp. Now I run:

```
g++ -o runner.exe runner.cpp -I "../lib/cxxtest-4.3" -std=c++11
```

This usually works fine, outputting runner.exe and running my unit tests. On my laptop I just get thousands of errors. Here's a look at just the first few:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\include\wchar.h:208:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\cwchar:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\istream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\sstream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\complex:45,
                 from ../lib/cxxtest-4.3/cxxtest/StdHeaders.h:24,
                 from ../lib/cxxtest-4.3/cxxtest/StdValueTraits.h:22,
                 from ../lib/cxxtest-4.3/cxxtest/ValueTraits.h:400,
                 from ../lib/cxxtest-4.3/cxxtest/TestSuite.h:24,
                 from ../lib/cxxtest-4.3/cxxtest/RealDescriptions.h:20,
                 from ../lib/cxxtest-4.3/cxxtest/TestRunner.h:22,
                 from runner.cpp:11:
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:173:14: error: '_dev_t' does not name a type
 struct _stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
              ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:173:14: error: '_ino_t' does not name a type
 struct _stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
              ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:173:14: error: '_mode_t' does not name a type
 struct _stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
              ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:173:14: error: '_dev_t' does not name a type
 struct _stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
              ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:173:14: error: '_off_t' does not name a type
 struct _stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
              ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:173:14: error: 'time_t' does not name a type
 struct _stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
              ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:173:14: error: 'time_t' does not name a type
 struct _stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
              ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:173:14: error: 'time_t' does not name a type
 struct _stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
              ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:180:13: error: '_dev_t' does not name a type
 struct stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
             ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:180:13: error: '_ino_t' does not name a type
 struct stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
             ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:180:13: error: '_mode_t' does not name a type
 struct stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
             ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:180:13: error: '_dev_t' does not name a type
 struct stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
             ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:180:13: error: '_off_t' does not name a type
 struct stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
             ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:180:13: error: 'time_t' does not name a type
 struct stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
             ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:180:13: error: 'time_t' does not name a type
 struct stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
             ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:180:13: error: 'time_t' does not name a type
 struct stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
             ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:188:17: error: '_dev_t' does not name a type
 struct _stati64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, time_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:188:17: error: '_ino_t' does not name a type
 struct _stati64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, time_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:188:17: error: '_mode_t' does not name a type
 struct _stati64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, time_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:188:17: error: '_dev_t' does not name a type
 struct _stati64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, time_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:188:17: error: '__off64_t' does not name a type
 struct _stati64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, time_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:188:17: error: 'time_t' does not name a type
 struct _stati64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, time_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:188:17: error: 'time_t' does not name a type
 struct _stati64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, time_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:188:17: error: 'time_t' does not name a type
 struct _stati64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, time_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:195:17: error: '_dev_t' does not name a type
 struct __stat64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, __time64_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:195:17: error: '_ino_t' does not name a type
 struct __stat64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, __time64_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:195:17: error: '_mode_t' does not name a type
 struct __stat64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, __time64_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:195:17: error: '_dev_t' does not name a type
 struct __stat64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, __time64_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:195:17: error: '__off64_t' does not name a type
 struct __stat64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, __time64_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:195:17: error: '__time64_t' does not name a type
 struct __stat64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, __time64_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:195:17: error: '__time64_t' does not name a type
 struct __stat64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, __time64_t );
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:195:17: error: '__time64_t' does not name a type
 struct __stat64 __struct_stat_defined( __off64_t, __time64_t );
```

When I run g++ on a simple hello world file, it works fine. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I also recently updated MinGW and ran into very very similar problems. After some research I found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433140/compilation-of-qt5-error-popen-was-not-declared-in-this-scope) and tried replacing `-std=c++11` with `-std=gnu++11`. This resolved the issue for me. Hope that helps!

Comment: Lukas - thank you! This was indeed the issue. I now see I have different versions of MinGW on each machine, something I should have picked up on.

Comment: I had this problem with CLion. I had to edit CMakeLists.txt and change -std=c++11 to -std=gnu++11 as you mentioned Lukas. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CMake, ensure you have

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS ON )
```

in your CMakeLists.txt file