# GEOS build errors

Tags: build, geos

The GEOS library [geos-3.5.0.tar.bz2](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/mingw64_how_to.html#libgeos) is failing during the make.Have seen similar SE query [MinGW / CxxTest bizarre errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436542/mingw-cxxtest-bizarre-errors) but I am not sure which file to change as the commands are in a configuration and makefile.

```
/bin/sh ../../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include/geos  -I../../../include   -DGEOS_INLINE  -pedantic -Wall -ansi -Wno-long-long  -ffloat-store -g -O2 -MT IndexedPointInAreaLocator.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/IndexedPointInAreaLocator.Tpo -c -o IndexedPointInAreaLocator.lo IndexedPointInAreaLocator.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../include -I../../../include/geos -I../../../include -DGEOS_INLINE -pedantic -Wall -ansi -Wno-long-long -ffloat-store -g -O2 -MT IndexedPointInAreaLocator.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/IndexedPointInAreaLocator.Tpo -c IndexedPointInAreaLocator.cpp -o IndexedPointInAreaLocator.o
In file included from c:\mingw\include\wchar.h:208:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\cwchar:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include\c++\string:40,
                 from ../../../include/geos/geom/Coordinate.h:24,
                 from ../../../include/geos/geom/Envelope.h:25,
                 from ../../../include/geos/geom/Geometry.h:27,
                 from IndexedPointInAreaLocator.cpp:17:
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:173:14: error: '_dev_t' does not name a type
 struct _stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
              ^
c:\mingw\include\sys/stat.h:173:14: error: '_ino_t' does not name a type
 struct _stat __struct_stat_defined( _off_t, time_t );
```

Comment: I've got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is I adopted is to change CXXFLAGS in Makefile per the SE suggestion at [G++ updated on MingW gets massive error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538924/g-updated-on-mingw-gets-massive-error-messages).

Searched for CXXFLAGS in Makefile
which looked like

```
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2
```

I changed it to

```
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 -std=gnu++11 -c -Wall
```

Since there are tens of Makefiles in the sub folders,I changed them using python batch script at one go.

```
import os, fnmatch
def findReplace(directory, find, replace, filePattern):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(filepath) as f:
                s = f.read()
            s = s.replace(find, replace)
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                f.write(s)

findReplace(r"C:\MinGW\git_rep\geos-3.5.0", "CXXFLAGS = -g -O2", "CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 -std=gnu++11 -c -Wall", "Makefile")
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem on x64 system using MinGW-x64 https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64