# MinGW 5.3.0-2 not working

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, mingw, codeblocks

I get a bizzare error after upgrading to MinGW 5.3.0-2(actual version)

[I checked everything because It's the 5th time i reinstall it and thought it would help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Imm.png)

Code::Blocks outputs this:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c C:\Users\Tudor\Documents\C++\test\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\test.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Note: if I check the -std=c++11 OR -std=c++14 flags i get output like here: [Click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538924/g-updated-on-mingw-gets-massive-error-messages)

Is it a problem with the last version of MinGW? If so where can I get the last working version? Or is anything in my computer messed up? I would like to keep this version if its possible to fix it but its getting me crazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't installed the Posix Threads (`pthread`) library, so the linker
can't find it. The particular Windows GCC packager that you have chosen doesn't
install it by default.

Start the MinGW Installation Manager and navigate **All Packages** -> **MinGW**
-> **MinGW Standard Libraries**. In the Standard Libraries presented, select
`mingw32-pthreads-w32 dev`. Then from the menubar select **Installation** -> **Apply Changes**
and proceed. Make it look like

[image: like this]

Newer Windows GCC packagers, e.g. [mingw-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/)
or [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/), will install pthreads by default and
provide 64- as well as 32-bit compilers. mingw-w64 in addition offers more up-to-date
versions of GCC (currently 6.2, which is the latest GCC release).

Answer (score 1):

If you use codeblocks-16.01-nosetup version or the earlier similar version then you need to install MinGW in home directory of C drive (C:\MinGW) and you have to add "C:\MinGW\bin" in the system variable called "Path".
However, I would recommend to use "codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe" version of codeblocks. This has a preloaded MinGW latest version. you can get it from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/16.01/Windows/codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe/download

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I had the nosteup version of codeblocks and MinGW in the C drive, also added "C:\MinGW\bin" to the path variable. . Everything was set up correctly. Everything was working fine... Until i updated MinGW to the newest version and at that point i got the error. Then i got an older version of MinGW and this one works. I think that somehow MinGW 5.0.3-2 is bugged :)

Comment: @TudorVersoiu: It's not "bugged"; it works for everyone else. Read the information given to you here.