# C++ error with CLion compile

Tags: c++, mingw, clion, jetbrains-ide

I got this error. http://pastebin.com/ujZVGaUy 
My settings: 
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSY5H.jpg)

A program dont say any errors, but compiler ;c

I have: Mingw with packages, CLion with student license.

My OS: Windows 10

Comment: you better post your error, and details of settings in text format right in your question. Because you cant trust external links. They may go away someday and then your question will be worthless to others.

Comment: also, look at this question of someone having a problem just like yours: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436542/mingw-cxxtest-bizarre-errors)

Comment: If you want to get "up votes" instead of "down votes" please read [How to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `-std=c++11` with `-std=gnu++11` in your CMakeLists.txt file.

More info:
[MinGW / CxxTest bizarre errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436542/mingw-cxxtest-bizarre-errors)