# mingw update compile with -std=c++11

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, mingw

I've noticed that with a new mingw version, I can't compile anymore with -std=c++11. It will outputs a bunch of errors, which can be "fixed" by using -std=gnu++11 ( [MinGW / CxxTest bizarre errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436542/mingw-cxxtest-bizarre-errors) ).

This quick hack works, but it doesn't fix the actual problem. How do I compile with c++11 flag? A lot of projects uses c++11, I don't want to change every makefiles to make it work, mingw should handle this ( in fact, It worked on my last version, before updating ).

Example code ( g++ Main.cpp -std=c++11 ):

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "ok...." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Errors: http://pastebin.com/Zcf8Qqhn

Comment: How about, make a man-in-the-middle executable that translates `-std=c++11` to `-std=gnu++11`? That said, you need to **include in the question** the test code, the compiler invocation verbatim, and ditto, the error messages verbatim. Voting to close as lacking reproducible example.

Comment: There you go. However, I am 100% sure it won't help you more since there was already an example of it in the linked question.

Comment: what is the output from `g++ --version`?

Comment: g++ (GCC) 5.3.0