# Compiling c++ files with sublime text

Tags: c++

I'm from VN so my English is not good.Sorry about that. My problem occurs when I try to compile my code C++ in sublime text 3 but it failed. Someone help me pls! I'm thanks a lots

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Your"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

ERROR:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from demo.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\cwchar:166:11: error: '::"vfwscanf"' has not been declared
  166 |   using ::**vfwscanf**;
      |           ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\cwchar:172:11: error: '::vswscanf' has not been declared
  172 |   using ::vswscanf;
      |           ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\cwchar:176:11: error: '::vwscanf' has not been declared
  176 |   using ::vwscanf;
      |           ^~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\cwchar:193:11: error: '::wcstof' has not been declared
  193 |   using ::wcstof;
      |           ^~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from demo.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\cwctype:89:11: error: '::iswblank' has not been declared
   89 |   using ::***iswblank***;
      |           ^~~~~~~~
[Finished in 0.6s]
```

Comment: So I copied and pasted your code in sublime text 3, saved the file as a cpp file and clicked build. It ran just fine. Your code is fine, I think the problem is one of two things. The errors mention an input file from elsewhere, which seems to be the thing throwing errors. Another thing may be how you have your sublime text 3 setup.

Comment: What OS are you using? What compiler? Have you tried compiling this directly on the command line? Please edit the question to add these details.

Comment: It seems like you use mingw compiler. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436542/mingw-cxxtest-bizarre-errors . Maybe this will help you